# IT is possible to call http images from wordpress site to my ssl site

Tags: wordpress

I want to dispaly post of non ssl wordpress site to my ssl site but while displaying images it gives mix content warning in console.
How to solve it pls help.

Comment: Hi,You have HTTPs in url

Comment: Yes.. my url  is https://www.moverjunction.com/

Comment: I have an solution.Go to your Media section

Comment: when you upload your image that time your SSL is not there thats why this image is go in http content.

Comment: @Vasim i want to use media in moving guides through http but in movejuction i want to acces to through https.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**
This is the simplest fix. If an asset (image, script, etc.) is hard-coded into a plugin or theme, change it from `http://example.com/assets/logo.png` to `https://example.com/assets/logo.png`.

Typically, this is most useful when including assets from other servers, like Google scripts, API scripts, or iframes.

Before doing this, however, you need to make sure the HTTPS version is available. If loading an asset from a site that doesn't have HTTPS enabled, it's probably best to remove the reference entirely (i.e. comment out or delete) or to save the asset to your own server and change the source to load via your site instead.

**Solution 2:**
References to your images are stored in your database, both in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables (in a standard install. You might have given your tables a prefix, but locating them should in any case be doable).

Since you mentioned using phpMyAdmin I guessed you are able editing the contents of your database with this tool.

Via phpMyAdmin you could manually locate and change the urls pointing to your images (removing the 'wp' part). But as this might be quite a few database entries, replacing all in one go is a more convenient decision.

I myself have had satisfactory results by

1. exporting the complete database as a .sql file through the phpMyAdmin export option.
2. editing this file with a text editor (converting the incorrect urls to the correct ones, make a backup copy first in case anything goes wrong, never forget the backup!)
3. deleting all database tables (for the wp install you're trying to correct)
4. importing the edited .sql file

Comment: Makes no sense. There is no difference in your URL fragments. And doesn't help since the point is there is no HTTPS version.